# Office 365 Activation Confuson

Tags: office365

I just installed Office 2016...I got these directions to follow but they're a little vague:

- Activate - me: done
- Sign in with an active account instead - me: what?

  - Use account you were supplied supplied
  - Uncheck stay logged in
- Accept defaults
- Use Recommended Settings
- Do not login

Are there two separate accounts at play here?   Why shouldn't I login with the last one?

Comment: This is rather hard to follow what you are asking. Are you asking which Microsoft ID to use? You should use the one associated with your Office 365 install you are attempting or it won't activate and install.

Comment: The activation goes fine.  But he doesn't want me to use the sign-in button that appears at the top of the office programs.

Comment: Now your question makes even less sense. If your activation was fine, why are you asking about it? Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking. And who is "*he*" that doesn't what you to use it?

Comment: At the top of the Word Window for instance, in the titlebar on the right just before the maximize, minimize, close buttons there is a sign-in button (assuming nobody is logged in) well there is in 2016 anyway.

Comment: You may want to give some screen shots.  If you have signed in and are activated - you should see your name in the upper right hand corner.